# Request parameters while consuming a REST API in node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, request

I would like to consume a REST service in Node.js using `request.js`, as follows:

```
var request = require('request');
request.get({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b',
  auth: {
    'bearer': 'oauth2_token'
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res.body);
});
```

However, I would like to specify also a set of request parameters, such as `project`, `prefix`, etc. (as specified at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list).

How can I pass these parameters in the request for consuming the API service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `qs` as the additional queries. See example below:

```
 const queryObject = { project: 'project', prefix: 'prefix' };

 request.get({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b',
    qs: queryObject,
    auth: {
      'bearer': "oauth2_token"
    }
  }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res.body);
  });
```

See [here for github issue](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2736).